# nodejs restclient authentication and fetch session data

Tags: node.js, authentication, rest-client

I am new nodejs, Currently I am using rest-client to fetch the data from proxy service. Initially By using POST method of rest Client I am able to login my proxy and I am getting a success response.

after login Immediately I am calling 'get'(proxy/user/me) method for fetching the session data, then I am facing login failed message, How can I will check each time before fetching any other data using nodejs.

```
//Example POST method invocation for Login
//after Login get method invocation

var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
var fs = require('fs');
var email = "raj@ioynx.io";
var proxy = "http://google.com";
var password = "abcd";
// set content-type header and data as json in args parameter
var args = {
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: email, password: password }),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
};

client.post(proxy+"login", args, function (data, response) {
    //Sucessfully Login message Dis[play with status Code 200
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    if (parseInt(response.statusCode) === 200) {
       //after success I am trying to fetch session Data, 'get' mehode will always shows ,there is no login.
        client.get(proxy+"user/me", function (sessionData, sessionResponse) {
            //The second URL for fetching session data always shows { message:  "not Login message" }       
            console.log(sessionData, 'Dubt', sessionResponse.statusCode);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap each method with some sort of authentication checker. Something like this-

```
function wrapAuthentication(fn) {
  return function() {
    // Check authentication
    if(authenticated) {
      fn.apply(fn, arguments);
    }
  }
}

function updateUserData() {
  // Do stuff 
}

client.post(proxy+"login", args, wrapAuthentication(updateUserData));
```

You're rest framework may support something like this already.